# Redirect url is not working even if enabled

Tags: 7, redirection

I am in upgrade phase of my site. After upgrade the redirect url is not working even if the status is enabled and no changes in redirect database the redirection url has stopped working. if I save them again without making any changes then the hash value of redirect table is changed and it started working again.

PS: I am not getting any error log for the same.

Is there anyway to fix such issue?

Comment: Did you run `yourwebsite.com/update.php`?

Comment: yes, It is working only if I edit and save the content